# Массивы в классе

Tags: php

Есть некий класс. В нем есть методы. Хочу написать коллектор ошибок, а потом выводить его результат в функции извне класса, как это сделать?

Пытался вот так:

```
class mySuperClass
{
    public $errors = array();

    private function ffff()
    {
        $this->errors[] = "error 1";
    }
    private function aaaa()
    {
        $this->errors[] = "error 2";
    }
    public function errorsShow()
    {
        var_dump($this->errors);
    }
}

$myVar = new mySuperClass();
function errorsCollector()
{
    $myVar->errorsShow();
}
```

Пример типа того, что выше. Не работает

update, реальный пример:

```
class loginAuthClass{

    // Фильтруем данные 
    private $authStatus = false; // Статус авторизации пользователя в системе 
    public $errors = array(); // Коллектор ошибок выводит ошибки в определенном методе

    protected function filterGlobalData($string,$ext_filter=false,$min=3,$max=32){

        if (empty($string)){
            $this->errors[] = "Переменная пустая!";
            return false;
        }

        // Если задается массив для фильтрации, то фильтруем его
        if ( is_array($string)){
            foreach ($string as $key => $value) {
                $string[$key] = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(stripslashes(trim($value))));
            }   
        } else {

            $string = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(stripslashes(trim($string))));

            if ( $ext_filter == true){
                if ( strlen($string) < $min || strlen($string) > $max || !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/", $string) ) {
                    $this->errors[] = "Неправильные символы или максимальное или минимальное число превышено!";
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return $string;
    }

    public function authAction(){

        /* 
        *   ----------------------------------------------------------
        *   Авторизация сравнивает куки с данными из базы данных и 
        *   устанавливает новое время куки для последующей авторизации
        *   Если куки не присутствуют, то возвращает false!
        *   ----------------------------------------------------------
        */

        $authData['user_id'] = false;
        $authData['user_hash'] = false;

        // -----------------------------
        // Проверяем куки у пользователя
        // -----------------------------
        if ( isset($_COOKIE['cookie_user_id']) && isset($_COOKIE['cookie_user_hash']) 
            and !empty($_COOKIE['cookie_user_id']) && !empty($_COOKIE['cookie_user_hash']) ) {

            $authData['user_id'] = $this->filterGlobalData($_COOKIE['cookie_user_id']);
            $authData['user_hash'] = $this->filterGlobalData($_COOKIE['cookie_user_hash']);
        }else{
            return false; // Возвращаем false потому, переменные для сравнения пустые или остутсвуют            
        }

        // -----------------------------
        // Сравниваем данные пользователя с базой
        // -----------------------------
        $query = "SELECT `userhash`, `username` FROM `users` WHERE `user_id`='".$authData['user_id']."' LIMIT 1";

        if ( ($result = mysqli_query($query)) == true){

            $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            // Сравниваем хеш куки и пользователя найденного в базе!
            if ($result['userhash'] === $authData['user_hash']){

                // ----------------------------------
                // Устанавливаем новое время для куки 
                // ----------------------------------

                # code....

                $this->authStatus = true;
            }
        } 
        return false;
    }

    public function loginAction(){

        if ( $authStatus == true) return true; // выходим из логинФормы

        $authLoginData['login_user_name'] = false;
        $authLoginData['login_user_password'] = false;

        if ( isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['userpassword']) ) {

            $authLoginData['login_user_name'] = $this->filterGlobalData($_POST['username'],$ext_filter=true,$min=4,$max=32);
            $authLoginData['login_user_password'] = $this->filterGlobalData($_POST['userpassword'],$ext_filter=true,$min=4,$max=32);
        }

        if ( $authLoginData['login_user_name'] != false && $authLoginData['login_user_password'] != false) {

            $this->errors[3] = "Результат фильтрации";
            return true;
        }
    }


    public function TooltipViewAction(){

        echo "<br>all errors-----------------------<br>";
        var_dump($this->errors);
        echo "<br>all errors-----------------------<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Как вы вызываете методы класса? Как именно не работает - ошибки, пустой экран?

Comment: Сперва объявляю новый экземпляр класса в переменную, а потом из переменной типа $peremenaja->Metod_iz_klassa()   var_dump выдает постоянно 0.     array(0) { }

Comment: Повторяю вопрос - Как вы вызываете методы класса?

Comment: $mainAuthClass = new loginAuthClass();
define("AUTH_STATUS",$mainAuthClass->authAction()); 
$mainAuthClass->TooltipViewAction(); Ошибки должны появится в TooltipViewAction();

примерно так!

Comment: Послушайте, вы в вопросе описываете один класс, в комментариях другой. Давайте уже определитесь какой конкретно класс у вас не работает и предоставьте его код.

Comment: Класс выше обновил. Только не смейтесь над кодом.

Comment: Какую-нибудь ошибку выдает?

Comment: Var_dump() выдает 
all errors-----------------------
array(0) { }
all errors-----------------------  постоянно во всех случаях

Comment: @jcmax Вы можете пользоваться Ctrl+K для форматирования кода (выделить код и нажать Ctrl+K).

Comment: спасибо незнал! постоянно проблема возникала с вставкой